# Testing R package: is it possible to make code aware that it is running in a test?

Tags: r, testthat

Is it possible to write a condition based on the fact that code is ran inside a test?

```
foo <- function() if(i_am_in_a_test_environment()) do_that() else do_this()
```

Comment: `?is_testing` perhaps?

Comment: Then you're not testing the code that runs when it's not a test, and there's not much point.

Comment: @jonrshape This is a trick to use the code where I set tests up outside tests. For example, I have this in a file `##tests/testthat/setup.R` `if(this_is_a_test) withr::defer(fs::dir_delete(subdir), teardown_env())`. `teardown_env()` means nothings outside `testthat`. So I could reproduce the setup outside tests for debugging.

Comment: Also in your test script you could `print( Sys.getenv() )` and look for things of interest (`is_testing` works by one such thing of interest, quite easily spotted)

Comment: @Sirius thx for sharing the process not only the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In his comment @Sirius told that he used `print(Sys.getenv())` to spot variables or functions concerning tests, he found `is_testing()`.

So the solution is:

```
foo <- function() if(is_testing()) do_that() else do_this()
```